# CursorAdapter and cursor.getPosition() not working

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a `ListView` that I'm filling with data from a `Cursor`. I have the `CursorAdapter`, and I want the last and first item to have different margins from the other items.

Previously I used this for a `ArrayAdapter` (and it worked perfectly)

```
float valueDips = 10.0f;
float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int valuePx = (int) (valueDips * scale + 0.5f);

if(position==0)
{
    View ll = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_girl);
    MarginLayoutParams margins = (MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
    margins.topMargin = valuePx;
    ll.setLayoutParams(margins);
}
if(position==data.size()-1)
{
    View ll = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_girl);
    MarginLayoutParams margins = (MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
    margins.bottomMargin = valuePx;
    ll.setLayoutParams(margins);
}
```

Now I want to use the same changing `position` to `cursor.getPosition()` inside the `if` statement, but it just won't work, because, for example, many items get a topMargin like the one inside the `if()`.

I'm thinking of creating an Object from my cursor and keep using an `ArrayAdapter`, but I think this would have a lower performance, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use if(cursor.isFirst()) for checking first item, and
if(cursor.isLast()) for checking last item.

Comment: Just tried this and it still happens... I don't know how different a `CursorAdapter` from an `ArrayAdapter` works, but I'm using the second one.

Comment: Using ArrayAdapter u can only map list  of items to maximum 2 views in listview(If you want to map multiple items try using a custom adapter by  extending BaseAdapter abstract class). CursorAdapter Helps you to map between db attributes and listview view items.

Comment: whats the data type for 'data'??

Comment: I have an `ArrayList<Car> data;` while Car is an `Object` I created with some `int` and `String`. In a near future it'll also have an image (I'm going to start working on that now).
With the `CursorAdapter` I got the data directly from the db, without creating an Array of `Car` objects, but I had that problem...

Answer (score 0):

Android re-use the view(list item view) in case of listview. So when you set margin for first view, many other views also have the same margin. In order to solve it you just have to set margins of each item. Do as follows.

```
    if(cursor.getPosition()==0 || cursor.getPosition()==data.size()-1)
    {
        View ll = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_girl);
        MarginLayoutParams margins = (MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
        margins.topMargin = valuePx;
        ll.setLayoutParams(margins);
    }
    else
    {
        //Set to the original value you have 
        View ll = view.findViewById(R.id.linear_girl);
        MarginLayoutParams margins = (MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
        margins.topMargin = original_value;
        ll.setLayoutParams(margins);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use header and footer view of list view.

```
View header, footer;
header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerlayout, null);
footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerlayout, null);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: Yes well, maybe i should have said use header and footer instead. But it is an answer.

Comment: how can it be an answer if you have the question mark at the end of the preposition :D?